# How to extract "original" content by xml-signed file

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature, xml-signature, envelope

I'm dealing with XML-signature. As you know, there are three types of XML signatures: enveloped, enveloping, detached.

I found nice tutorials about how to use java standard API to sign/verify file but I would like to know how to extract the (almost) "original" content data. In particular:

1) After validating an **Enveloped**  XML signed file, what is the right way to "get" the XML content without signature?

2) After validating an **Enveloping** XML signed file, what is the right way to "get" the "Object" node?

For "get" I mean writing on a separate physical file, cleaning signature (with standard API, if possible).

Thank you in advance,

kindly.

Mirko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Enveloped signature**

```
<yourxml>
   ...
   <Signature>....</Signature>
</yourxml>
```

The signature is a node of the XML document. After validating the XML Signature, find the node, remove it of DOM structure and save the document.

```
// Instantiate the document to be signed.
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream(xml));

// Find Signature element.
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature");

//... XML Signature validation

//remove signature node from DOM
nl.item(0).getParentNode().removeChild(nl.item(0));

//write to file.
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));
```

**Enveloping signature**

```
<Signature>
   <Object Id="object">
      <yourxml>...</yourxml>
    </Object>
 </Signature>
```

You could apply the same technique. Find the `Object` node and save the first child to a file. But in this case, the `XMLSignature` provides `getObjects` method to get the signed objects

```
//XMLSignature result of validation process
XMLSignature signature = ...

//Gets the node
XMLObject xmlObject = (XMLObject)signature.getObjects().get(0);
Node yourXmlNode = ((DOMStructure)xmlObject.getContent().get(0)).getNode();

//Save to file
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
trans.transform(new DOMSource(yourXmlNode), new StreamResult(os));
```

Answer (score 1):

In the @pedrofb answer for the enveloping case, the code works if object data is XML-structured. However I have a *flat data* in the object node, so I obtain the original data content using similar technique:

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Object");
if (nl.getLength() == 0) {
    throw new Exception("*** Cannot find Object element");
}
final String data = nl.item(0).getTextContent();

try {
    File target = new File("/path/output.dat");

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(target);
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer, 8192);
    bufferedWriter.write(data);

    //flush & close writers
    //...

} catch (Exception e) {
    //...

}
```